# M-S-up/down in org-mode suddenly does not 'move' whole items anymore

Tags: org-mode, emacs25, emacs26

Consider a `.org` file containing

```
* Item 1
  - Item 1.1
  - Item 1.2
* Item 2
  - Item 2.1
  - Item 2.2
```

with the point being at `Item 2`. With GNU Emacs 25.2.1
(x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0) of 2017-04-21 and Org-mode version 8.2.10 executing `M-S-up` leads to

```
* Item 2
  - Item 2.1
  - Item 2.2
* Item 1
  - Item 1.1
  - Item 1.2
```

With GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0) of 2018-05-30 and
Org-mode version 9.1.9, I suddenly see this (on `M-S-up`):

```
* Item 1
  - Item 1.1
* Item 2
  - Item 1.2
  - Item 2.1
  - Item 2.2
```

Has this (default) behaviour changed? And how do you get the 'old' behaviour?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49953612/move-item-with-underlying-text-in-orgmode) seems to be related but the answer does not seem helpful in this regard.

Is there any way to get the old behavior back? The new behavior is inconsistent with how meta-left/right and shift-meta-left/right works. Here shift-meta-left/right moves the subtree while meta-left/right moves a line. In contrast, with up and down shift-meta-up/down moves a line and meta-up/down the subtree. This new behavior of meta-shift-up/down moving only a line drives me completely bonkers when trying to move a subtree to its correct position in a hierarchy. I never remember when to press shift and when not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The keybinding for `org-move-subtree-up` is `M-up`. I don't remember what it was before and a cursory look through git history and the [ORG-NEWS](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/master/etc/ORG-NEWS) file did not uncover any change, but I might have missed it.

Edit: I tried 8.2.10 and confirmed the behavior you described. I then did a git bisect and found the change:

> commit b978abb485cd4fbe8d32f5440ce91b707e7d2b16
>   Author: Bastien Guerry 
>   Date:   Thu May 29 19:25:08 2014 +0200

```
org.el (org-shiftmetaup, org-shiftmetadown): Update behavior

* org.el (org-shiftmetaup, org-shiftmetadown): Don't move the
subtree or list item at point up or down, as this feature is
already accessible through `org-metaup' and `org-metadown'.
Update the docstrings to reflect the new behavior.
```

That happened between the 8.2.10 and 8.3 releases.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. Not sure why `M-S-up` was the same behaviour as `M-up` under the "old versions".